# How can i use variable from controller to the master blade layout? Route?

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I am trying to pass variable in layout.member (this is my master blade)

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;

class ChangeNotificationSetting extends Controller
{

public function index()
{
    //  $user = Auth::user();

    $user_id = Auth::user()->id;

    View::composer('layouts.member', function($view)
    {
        $user_name = Auth::user()->name;
        $view->with('name', Auth::check() ? Auth::user()->name : '');
    });

}
```

Should I require to route for this? 
I am trying to use `{{DD($user_name)}}` variable into layouts.member but error :

> Undefined variable:

Provider:
[Provider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Szby.jpg)

Changed Namespace[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bYCAv.jpg)

Comment: you are registering a view composer from a controller method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you pass name variable and try to access username variable you can access it as the following:

```
View::composer('layouts.member', function($view)
{
    $view->with('user_name', Auth::check() ? Auth::user()->name : '');
});
```

Comment: Your code giving me error `Undefined variable: user_name (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\development\fresh\ytl\resources\views\layouts\member.blade.php)`

Comment: are you sure you added this provider to app

Comment: App\Providers\YourPtoviderNam::class,

Comment: inside this path config\app.php

Comment: which `YourPtoviderNam` should i use ? `'View' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\View::class,`

Comment: your provider name the name of the class

Comment: its means my provider is `ChangeNotificationSetting `, right?

Comment: the class name which contains this code View::composer('layouts.member', function($view)
{
    $view->with('user_name', Auth::check() ? Auth::user()->name : '');
});

Comment: another error : `Class 'App\Providers\ChangeNotificationSetting'` not found

Comment: are you sure the ChangeNotificationSetting exists in this path App\Providers

Comment: I have attached screenshot in question at bottom of question. @ali

Comment: can make screenshot for your provider

Comment: it must be like this namespace App\Providers; in the code image

Comment: and remove this line use App\Providers\ChangeNotificationsSettings;

Comment: yes now i changed it. and also attached screen shot

Comment: its has been solved with `AppServiceProvider` with `boot` method. thank you @ali